# why synchronized object can still be manipulated

Tags: multithreading, synchronized

Code snippet like below:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

public void addValue(int i) {
    synchronized (list) {
        list.add("list" + i);
    }
}
```

My question is that what is locked by keyword `synchronized`.
What will be checked of the `list` when two threads are asking to execute the code block?
The same question is that I synchronized `this` but its fields can still be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The synchronized block is locked. When the code runs, a thread does not lock the object, instead, it **OBTAINS** the lock of the `list` object,(which is a mark word inside the object header) so other thread cannot obtain the same lock. As a result, the code inside the block can only be executed by one thread at the same time.